# Kotlin: how to pass array to Java annotation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I want to use `@OneOf` annotation from `package io.dropwizard.validation;`

Java usage:

```
@OneOf(value = {"m", "f"})
```

Kotlin usage: ???

I've tried this:

```
 @OneOf(value = arrayOf("m", "f"))
```

and this:

```
 @OneOf(value = ["m", "f"])
```

(EDIT: this example works since Kotlin 1.2, it supports array literal in annotation, thanks @BakaWaii)

All i get is :

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:
>
> required: String
>
> found: `Array<String>`

Kotlin version: 1.1.2-2

Comment: To pass an array as a vararg parameter, use spread (*) operator. `@OneOf(value = *arrayOf("m", "f"))`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `value` parameter is automatically converted to a vararg parameter in Kotlin, as described in http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#java-annotations.

The correct syntax for this particular case is `@OneOf("m", "f")`

Answer (score 23):

In Kotlin 1.2, it supports array literal in annotation. So the below syntax becomes valid in Kotlin 1.2:

```
@OneOf(value = ["m", "f"])
```

Answer (score 7):

As an example from [Kotlin docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#java-annotations)

```
// Kotlin 1.2+:
@OneOf(names = ["abc", "foo", "bar"]) 
class C

// Older Kotlin versions:
@OneOf(names = arrayOf("abc", "foo", "bar")) 
class D
```

Comment: any idea how to pass this as a variable? 
like, val someArray = arrayOf("abc", "foo", "bar")
I tried it below way and its giving me `should be compile time constant exception`
1) 
@OneOf(names = someArray) 
2) 
@OneOf(names = *someArray)

Answer (score 0):

Example of annotation parameters other than value. Non-literals can also be passed inside []

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{isbn}", method=[RequestMethod.GET])
fun getBook(@PathVariable isbn: String) : Book = bookRepository.findBookByIsbn(isbn)
```