# Kotlin 1.1.60 does not accept array as value for spring RequestMapping

Tags: spring, controller, kotlin

I'm trying to add the following annotation to an endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = arrayOf("path/1", "path/2"))
fun myEndpoint() { ... }
```

The Kotlin compiler complains that value only accepts `String` and not `Array<String>` while the documentation of the annotation clearly states that value accepts String[]. Any idea how to fix this?

Kotlin Version 1.1.60, Spring 4.3.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after the correct answer was deleted for some reason I will repeat it:

```
@GetMapping("path/1", "path/2")
fun myEndpoint() { ... }
```

works. As @yole answered [Kotlin: how to pass array to Java annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069045/kotlin-how-to-pass-array-to-java-annotation) "The value parameter is automatically converted to a vararg parameter in Kotlin, as described in http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#java-annotations."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@GetMapping(value = ["some thing", "another some thing"])
```

In my env works properly with Spring Beans and Controler Mapping.

Comment: Only available in Kotlin 1.2 :-(

Comment: Sorry I've just noticed that I have 1.2 Kotlin